# How can we give vertical space between text-fileds using auto-layouts programatically(constraintsWithVisualFormat)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

i am beginner in iOS and in my project i am adding some textfields on `UIView` programatically using auto-layouts(`constraintsWithVisualFormat`) but space between two text fields is not fixing.

According to my code i got result like second screen shot but i want to get result like first screen. Please help me in resolving this issue. I want to set vertical space between two text fields like "50")

### This is my code:-

```
    textFiedl1 = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    textFiedl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textFiedl1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [myView addSubview:textFiedl1];

    textField2 = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    textField2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textField2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [myView addSubview:textField2];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(textFiedl1,textField2);


    NSArray * textFieldConstraint1H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textFiedl1]-10-|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views];

    NSArray * textFieldConstraint2H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textField2]-10-|"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:views];


NSArray * textFieldConstraintV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[textFiedl1(30)]-50-[textField2(30)]-|"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:views];
```

but i want get result like below screen shot please help me some one i would be grateful to you. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the last `-|` which means the second textfield should be close to the bottom of superview.

```
NSArray * textFieldConstraintV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[textFiedl1(30)]-50-[textField2(30)]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:views];
```

Comment: @Ramakrishna - You should accept this answer if it resolved your problem.